# MySQL failed login attempt on startup

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I've recently noticed that in my /var/log/mysql/error.log I keep getting the following:

> Version: '5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'  socket:
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
>   2016-12-25T17:36:06.356990Z 2
>   [Note] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Each and every time MySQL is restarted. I don't understand why this is happening. My grant tables are fine, and my root user is working well and I can access it any time.

This tells me that something is trying to login to the server during startup, but I don't know where/what to look for to fix this.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1**

Here are the parts I can share from `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_warnings = 2
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
```

Comment: Could you show us your my.cnf settings without sharing anything too sensitive?  You should be able to find it in one of these locations: 
    /etc/my.cnf
    /etc/mysql/my.cnf
    $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
    [datadir]/my.cnf
    ~/.my.cnf

Comment: Added details under Edit 1, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange one! I also had this issue in my logs when I checked which led me to a search where I found this post: https://github.com/andryyy/mailcow/issues/619

Following "admf's" lead what I did was restart my mysql daemon, service mysqld restart and confirm the root access was being denied.  Then I went into the mysql client as root and used the ALTER command on 'root'@'localhost', like so:

```
 ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YourPassword';
```

Then run

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Then restart mysql again

```
service mysqld restart
```

And now that failed login no longer appears as part of the startup notices in the log.  What's strange is that I already had a password and permissions set in my tables some time ago.  Must be something quirky with recent updates in MySQL but at least it works!

Comment: Tried that, sadly it didn't do the trick. And yes I already had a password set too.

Comment: I am on `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-59-generic x86_64)` running `5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`, with an almost identical entry every time mysql server starts and I cannot get rid of the message. The above suggestion did not help.